# iOS - Accessing text variable in Picker View to use in Notification Sound Name

Tags: ios, objective-c, localnotification

I have this first method for scheduling local notification:

```
- (void) scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate:(NSDate *)fireDate
{
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.fireDate = fireDate;
    notification.category = @"Alarm";
    notification.soundName = @"Pager.caf";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: notification];
}
```

Then, I created a Picker View where the user can choose the alarm tone in the list with this method:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
      inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *resultString = _alarmNames[row];
    _alarmToneText.text = resultString;
}
```

Now, I want to edit the scheduleNotification method to call the text value in picker view which is **resultString** and put it in notification.soundName.

Here is what the code would look like:

```
notification.soundName = resultString;
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I want to make this code work, notification.soundName = resultString; I need to get the variable resultString from pickerView method and use it in my notification.soundName

Comment: You can't change notification text after it is been scheduled. You should change signature of your method to something like ```- (void) scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate:(NSDate *)fireDate andSound:(NSString*)sound``` and call it from ```-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row```.

Comment: I'd updated scheduleLocalNotification method but how do I call it from pickerView method? Sorry for being a noob.

Comment: you mean first you will select sound name and then create localNotification.? Right?

Comment: Yes, select sound name and then create localNotification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSString *soundName;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    soundName = @"";
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    soundName = _alarmNames[row];
}

- (void) scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate:(NSDate *)fireDate
{
    if (![soundName isEqualToString:@""]) {
        UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notification.fireDate = fireDate;
        notification.category = @"Alarm";
        notification.soundName = soundName;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: notification];
    } else {
        // Show alert for select sound
    }

}
```

There is no need to show TextFied for selected Sound file name. [This is best practice ever.]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll remember this from now on.